# ORA - 00933 confusion with inner join and "as"

Tags: sql, oracle, join, table-alias

I have this query of getting data from two tables using an `inner join`, but I get the error `SQL command not properly ended` with an asterix under "as":

```
select P.carrier_id, O.order_id, O.aircraft_id, O.quantity

from orderline AS O

inner join purchaseorder AS P

on O.order_id = P.carrier_id;

the error:

from orderline AS O ( with an asterix under AS)


Error at line 2
Ora-00933: SQL command not properly ended.
```

In regards to this I thought that `AS` wouldn't be an issue as it's just referencing an alias, but I'm so confused as to why this is coming up.

Comment: Just remove the `as`. You use `AS` For column aliasing, but table aliasing doesn't need an `as`. `Select * From Orderline O `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `AS` keyword

```
select 
   P.carrier_id, 
   O.order_id, 
   O.aircraft_id, 
   O.quantity
from 
   orderline O
inner join purchaseorder P
   on O.order_id = P.carrier_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to insert keyword `as` between table name and its alias.